# How to get Previous date Angular date picker

Tags: angular, datepicker, angular-material

I'm using Angular Material DatePicker like this

```
<input matInput [(ngModel)]="selectedDate" [max]="today" (dateChange)="onDateSelect($event)"
              [matDatepicker]="picker" readonly />
```

And I need to set the last selected date in

> onDateSelect()

function. the function is like follows

```
 onDateSelect(event) {
    if(some condition){
      this.selectedDate = <//set previous date>
    }
    this.selectedDate = event.value;   
 }
```

how can I pass the previous date to the above function

Comment: What does previous date reflect ?. The day before of the selected date or any other date apart from selected date

Comment: the previous date means, the date that was recorded before the date was changed from the calendar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

another option is use a FormControl, and pairwise

```
selectedDate=new FormControl()
ngOnInit()
{
   this.selectedDate.valueChanges.pipe(
      startWith(this.selectedDate.value), //it's necesary send a first value
      pairwise())  //the pairwise make the "magic"
 .subscribe(([old,value])=>{
    if (old!=value)
    {
       console.log("I change from "+old+" to "+value)
    }
 })

<input matInput [formControl]="selectedDate" [max]="today" 
           [matDatepicker]="picker" readonly />
```

[see the stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dfetgd?file=src/app/datepicker-overview-example.ts)

Comment: Thanks, @Eliseo, but the thing is the date can change multiple times. I need to track each and every change with the previous value.

Comment: I just add a stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dfetgd?file=src/app/datepicker-overview-example.ts

Answer (score 0):

Create a variable prevSelectedDate as null and add please add the below changes in code.

```
onDateSelect(event) {

if(some condition && this.prevSelectedDate){
  this.selectedDate = this.prevSelectedDate;
}
this.selectedDate = event.value;  
this.prevSelectedDate =  this.selectedDate
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You need 2 variables for it, something like below:

Reset to previous if your validation is not passed.

JS:

```
export class DatepickerApiExample implements OnInit {
  previousVal: any;
  curVal: any;
  checkPassed: true;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.previousVal = this.curVal;
  }

  onDateSelect($event: any) {
    if (this.checkPassed) {
      this.previousVal = this.curVal;
    } else {
      //Reset to previous
      this.curVal = this.previousVal;
    }
  }
}
```

HTML:

```
<mat-form-field class="example-full-width" appearance="fill">
  <mat-label>Choose a date</mat-label>
  <input matInput [(ngModel)]="curVal" [max]="today" (dateChange)="onDateSelect($event)" [matDatepicker]="picker">
  <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```

Comment: Thanks, @huan, but the thing is the date can change multiple times. I need to track each and every change with the previous value